# how to disable MobileSafari auto-selection?

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

my webapp requires users to tap and hold on an element for a game action,
 but iPhone automatically "selects" the area which is confusing to the user.

anyone know what html elements prevent selection, or if javascript can block selection?

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try handling the `selectstart` event and returning `false`.

Try applying the CSS rule, `-webkit-user-select: none;`

Answer (score 14):

SLaks answer is obviously right - I just want to extend it a bit for future viewers. If you're using jQuery, here's a useful extension method that disables selection in various browsers:

```
$.fn.extend({ 
        disableSelection : function() { 
                this.each(function() { 
                        this.onselectstart = function() { return false; }; 
                        this.unselectable = "on"; 
                        $(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none'); 
                        $(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none'); 
                }); 
        } 
});
```